# Пунктуация: запятая или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, двоеточие, бессоюзное

**Эй, стонущий, работай и не плачь(?) для мнительных работа — лучший врач.**

Какой знак препинания (запятая или двоеточие) должен стоять в указанном месте?
Одно из условий постановки двоеточия — причинное (можно вставить *потому что, так как*): *Печален я: со мною друга нет.*
Но везде на этом месте стоит запятая. Как тогда объяснить?

Answer (score 1):

**Эй, стонущий, работай и не плачь, для мнительных работа — лучший врач.**

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение (БСП), где обычно делается выбор между **тремя знаками**: тире, двоеточием и запятой.

Второе предложение действительно обозначает **причину** первого, и по классическим правилам мы должны поставить двоеточие. Но как известно, в современном языке тире может заменять двоеточие, также может ставиться и запятая.

**Как же сделать выбор?** Двоеточие используется,  если мы хотим точно указать, где причина, а где следствие. Если нам достаточно просто обозначить причинно-следственные отношения, то ставим тире. В обоих случаях делается пауза, только для двоеточия она более длительная.

**А запятая?** Запятая обозначает, что второе предложение **распространяет первое,** то есть продолжает ту же мысль, в том числе может обозначать отношения причины и следствия. Пауза присутствует, но не подчеркивается, как в случае тире или двоеточия.

Обратим внимание на то, что причинно-следственные отношения между предложениями  в нашей речи присутствуют часто, то **мы далеко не всегда используем такие сильные знаки, как тире и двоеточие.**